# Sencha Touch Native Applicaiton or PhoneGap able to run in Window Operating System or not?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

Because Now the device are using Android Operating system,
but one days we may found the limitation or security reason of Android, and that time we able to switch the application from android to window operating system,
isn't it the **Sencha Touch Native Application** or **PhoneGap** able to run in Window Operating System or not?

Comment: What Windows OS are you talking about? Windows Phone 8? Or Windows 8? or...

Comment: @arthurakay Window XP/7/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Touch (and by proxy, and web-based framework) cannot run as a "native" Windows XP/7 desktop application unless you compile it with a tool for that purpose. Sencha used to have a desktop packager, but has discontinued it - there are alternatives listed [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271422-Transition-plan-amp-alternatives-now-that-Desktop-Packager-is-discontinued).

I've only ever used Cordova/PhoneGap for mobile apps, but according to their website it does support compiling to Windows desktop.

Another option would be to build a Chrome packaged app (runs in Chrome browser, but can be distributed).

Lastly, Windows 8 apps can be natively written with JavaScript - but that's only available in Win8, not XP/7.